# Filtering certain items from a python list of links generated by beatifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper to scrape some information off of the website [JW Pepper](http://jwpepper.com) for a sheet music database. I am using BeautifulSoup and python to do this.

Here is my code:

```
# a barebones program I created to scrape the description and audio file off the JW pepper website, will eventually be used in a music database
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
linkgot = 0
def linkget():
    search = "http://www.jwpepper.com/sheet-music/search.jsp?keywords=" # this is the url without the keyword that comes up when searching something
    print("enter the name of the desired piece")
    keyword = raw_input("> ") # this will add the keyword to the url
    url = search + keyword
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    all_links = soup.findAll("a")
    link_dict = []
    item_dict = []
    for link in all_links:
         link_dict.append(link.get('href')) # adds a list of the the links found on the page to link_dict
    item_dict.append(x for x in link_dict if '.item' in x) #sorts them occording to .item
    print item_dict

linkget()
```

The "print" command returns this: [ at 0x10ec6dc80>], which returns nothing when I google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filtering of the list was going wrong. Rather than filter in a seperate loop, you could just build the list if `.item` is present as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def linkget():
    search = "http://www.jwpepper.com/sheet-music/search.jsp?keywords=" # this is the url without the keyword that comes up when searching something
    print("enter the name of the desired piece")
    keyword = raw_input("> ") # this will add the keyword to the url
    url = search + keyword
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    link_dict = []
    item_dict = []

    for link in soup.findAll("a", href=True):
        href = link.get('href')
        link_dict.append(href)  # adds a list of the the links found on the page to link_dict

        if '.item' in href:
            item_dict.append(href)

    for href in item_dict:
        print href

linkget()
```

Giving you something like:

```
/Festival-of-Carols/4929683.item
/Festival-of-Carols/4929683.item
/Festival-of-Carols/4929683.item
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems like I still have much to learn on filters.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick by the answer to accept it as the solution (and get a badge).